# Why doesn't "extend" add a constant to a class while "include" does?

Tags: ruby, class, module

I have the following code:

```
module Books
  MINBOOKPRICE = 10
end
```

This is supposed to add module stuff at class level:

```
class BuySoon
  extend Books
end
```

but:

```
BuySoon::MINBOOKPRICE #=> NameError: uninitialized constant BuySoon::MINBOOKPRICE
```

Instead, if I do this, which is supposed to add module stuff at `BuySoon` instances level:

```
class BuySoon
  include Books
end
```

then I get

```
BuySoon::MINBOOKPRICE #=> 10
```

Am I doing something wrong in how I am setting the constant in the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include` “enhances instance” while `extend` “enhances class itself.” Constant is a property of a class (belongs to class’ scope,) that’s why enhancing instance with `include` you automatically get the class constant defined. Think of `include` directive is of “inline“ function in `c++`: the code is virtually being copy-pasted inplace of `include` directive.

Whether you call extend, the eigenclass is to be enhanced. Therefore the constant will be available at `BuySoon.singleton_class::MINBOOKPRICE`. In other words, the code is similar to:

**include:**

```
class BuySoon
  MINBOOKPRICE = 10
end
```

**extend:**

```
class BuySoon
  class << self
    MINBOOKPRICE = 10
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What you say make sense, at least the part I got, but I think you got downvoted for writing in a non clear way. I think what you wanted to say is that if you enhance class with "extend" then the constant will be available at `BuySoon.singleton_class::MINBOOKPRICE` because extends adds things at the class singleton class level. This explains why the constant is not available on BuySoon but I still don't understand the other part. Why is constant available on class after I "include" module on class? The part you say about constant being a class variable, still can't understand it..

Comment: mud, I thought your answer was quite clear. And if you both `include` and `extend`, you have two unrelated constants with the the same name: `BuySoon.singleton_class::MINBOOKPRICE => 10; BuySoon.singleton_class::MINBOOKPRICE = 9; BuySoon.singleton_class::MINBOOKPRICE => 9;
Books::MINBOOKPRICE => 10`. Hmmm. no warning about changing the valiue of the constant in the singleton class. I wonder why.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think (can’t find any documentation on the topic, though,) that until you have explicitly defined `BuySoon.singleton_class.const_set :MINBOOKPRICE, 9`, ruby internally has no value for `BuySoon::MINBOOKPRICE` and hence uses the `Books::MINBOOKPRICE` instead. As soon as you have it explicitly defined on `BuySoon`, this new value is being stored. The second call to `BuySoon::MINBOOKPRICE = ...` will throw a warning.

Comment: We can test that: `BuySoon.include Books; BuySoon::MINBOOKPRICE = 5; BuySoon::MINBOOKPRICE => 5;
Books::MINBOOKPRICE => 10; BuySoon.extend Books; BuySoon.singleton_class::MINBOOKPRICE => 10; BuySoon.singleton_class::MINBOOKPRICE = 20; 
BuySoon.singleton_class::MINBOOKPRICE => 20;
BuySoon.singleton_class::MINBOOKPRICE = 50 =>warning: already initialized constant Class::MINBOOK`.  That's interesting.